# How to send captured image directly to the other application

Tags: android

How to send captured imaged directly from my custom camera to other application? For example, other application request camera to take photos and instead of using stock camera, shall we say i used my custom camera. My problem is, how to send the captured image directly to the requesting party? i'd try parsing the imagepath but it doesn't work. All i want is the binary data or the image data sent directly to the requesting party. Thanks

I am trying to follow this code but no luck..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this,FullScreenActivity.class);
            Drawable drawable   = imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_IMG, bitmap);
            startActivity(intent);
```

because i dont have imageView, i am using PictureCallback. It is applicable if i'd use PictureCallback instead of imageView?

Comment: You can use ShareActionProvider to share your images. Try this, its pretty simple http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: Please read through this . It will help. (I dont think the above one is ur requirement) http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: This is directly sent image from the camera? and the user have the final action to save the captured image?

Comment: Can you give me some example sir? Like intent or any that can send my captured image directly to the requesting party like my tracks.

Comment: @user3378678 in this method, we can send image/text to other app. But I dont know hot to access Camera. I couldn't find any intent-filters for do that. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html